# How to load different ads at different position in recylerview android

Tags: android, admob, android-recyclerview

I have implemented ads in my project in recyclerview. My requirement is to load different ads at different positions like facebook or other android application shows, but I'm unable to load different ads at different positions, same ad is getting loaded at each position.

This is the method that I'm using for loading ads.

```
public void loadAd(final Context context,
                   final AppInstallAdViewHolder viewHolder) {

    synchronized (mSyncObject) {

        if ((mAdLoader != null) && mAdLoader.isLoading()) {
           Log.d("MainActivity.LOG_TAG", "AppInstallAdFetcher is already loading an ad.");
            return;
        }

        // If an ad previously loaded, reuse it instead of requesting a new one.
        if (viewHolder.mAppInstallAd != null) {
            viewHolder.populateView(context,viewHolder.mAppInstallAd);
            return;
        }

        NativeAppInstallAd.OnAppInstallAdLoadedListener appInstallAdListener =
                new NativeAppInstallAd.OnAppInstallAdLoadedListener() {
                    public void onAppInstallAdLoaded(NativeAppInstallAd ad) {
                        viewHolder.mAppInstallAd = ad;
                        viewHolder.populateView(context,viewHolder.mAppInstallAd);
                    }
                };

        if (mAdLoader == null) {
            mAdLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(context, ConstantVariables.NATIVE_AD_UNIT_ID)
                            .forAppInstallAd(appInstallAdListener)
                    .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                            mViewHolder.hideView();
                        }
                    }).build();
        }
        mAdLoader.loadAd(new PublisherAdRequest.Builder()
                .build());
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot in advanced !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Dont't do that.**

your admob account will get banned if you will put more than one ads on single page with same id.

You can do it by creating muliple ad ids. But for that you need to create lot of ads id to show it in `RecyclerView`.

> The number of ads on a single screen should not exceed one

checkout official docs under [Ad Placement](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en)

Comment: Ok got that, but I have a doubt that how facebook and other android applications handle this. Can you please give us an example or some guidance here.

Thanks

Comment: I have given official doc link, and i dont think facebook is using admob in application.

Comment: Ok. can we load multiple NativeAds in our application ?

Comment: yes you can, but you need multiple ad ids. with single ad id you can load only one ad in single page.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, override getItemViewType method:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    int id_of_your_type;
     //Implement your logic here
    return id_of_your_type;
}
```

Then you can simply use the second parameter of the onCreateViewHolder and switch between your views and ads  :
you should have created a holder for each view.

```
 @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
        View v=null;
          RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder = null;
            switch(viewType){
                case TYPE_Ad1:
                    v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.layout1, viewGroup, false);
                 holder = new TYPE_Ad1_Holder();                
                 break;
                case TYPE_2:
                    v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.layout2, viewGroup, false);

                    holder = new Type2_Holder();                
                    break;
                case TYPE_Ad2:
                    v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                            .inflate(R.layout.layout3, viewGroup, false);

                    holder = new TYPE_Ad2_Holder();                
                    break;
            }
        return holder;
    }
```